# Lógica de consulta MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Amigo/as buenas noches, quisiera pedirles de vuestra ayuda ya que estoy bloqueado en cuanto a la lógica de una consulta en mi BD.

Planteo el problema:
Necesito saber cuantos consumos tuvo una persona en el restaurante, esto incluye clasificarse por desayuno, almuerzo y cena, también clasifico por tipo de alimento por Rancho(frío(Ejp:yogurt, leche, sandwich) o normal(comida normal)), de ese modo, necesitaría sacar un reporte al mes donde se especifique cuantos desayunos, almuerzos y cenas fueron de rancho Frío y de Rancho normal.

Query:

```
SELECT empresa.idempresa, empresa.nombre AS empresa, comensal.idcomensal, comensal.dni, comensal.nombres, consumo.create_date  AS Fecha,
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_ran LIKE '%normal%' THEN 1 END) AS Normal,
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_ran LIKE '%frio%' THEN 1 END) AS Frio,
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_pla LIKE '%Desayuno%' THEN 1 END) AS Desayunos,
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_pla LIKE '%Almuerzo%' THEN 1 END) AS Almuerzo,
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_pla LIKE '%Cena%' THEN 1 END) AS Cena
FROM `consumo`
LEFT JOIN comensal ON consumo.idcomensal = comensal.idcomensal
LEFT JOIN empresa ON empresa.idempresa = comensal.idempresa
WHERE create_date = '2018-08-14'
GROUP BY comensal.nombres
```

Lo que me genera el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde no logro clasificar el consumo por tipo de rancho (cuantos desayunos, almuerzos y cenas fueron de Rancho frío o Rancho Normal).

Mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia o comentario. Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer mi pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que en la comparación de que plato es, añadas también el tipo de Rancho, algo asi...

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_ran LIKE '%normal%' AND consumo.tipo_pla LIKE '%Desayuno%' THEN 1 END) AS Normal_desayuno,
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_ran LIKE '%frio%' AND consumo.tipo_pla LIKE '%Desayuno%' THEN 1 END) AS Frio_desayuno,
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_ran LIKE '%normal%' AND consumo.tipo_pla LIKE '%Almuerzo%' THEN 1 END) AS Normal_almuerzo,
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_ran LIKE '%frio%' AND consumo.tipo_pla LIKE '%Almuerzo%' THEN 1 END) AS Frio_almuerzo,
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_ran LIKE '%normal%' AND consumo.tipo_pla LIKE '%Cena%' THEN 1 END) AS Normal_cena,
COUNT(CASE WHEN consumo.tipo_ran LIKE '%frio%' AND consumo.tipo_pla LIKE '%Cena%' THEN 1 END) AS Frio_cena
```

Y asi clasificas cada rancho con cada tipo de plato a la vez.